# 'Missing name for redirect.' error in while running command in CSH environment

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I am trying to generate some certificate using below command in CSH environment:

```
/usr/bin/openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout "selfsigned.key" \
-out "selfsigned.crt" -subj "/C=XX/ST=XX/L=XX/O=XX/OU=XX/CN=Some IP" -extensions SAN \
-config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:Some DNS,Some IP"))
```

Getting *`Missing name for redirect`* error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Part of your command line is:

```
… <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:Some DNS,Some IP"))
```

You're using a Bash-specific notation — [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) — twice.  In the C shell, that simply isn't going to work. The C shell has no clue what you mean (witness the error message).

You'll have to wrap the command in a Bash script and use Bash to execute it.  Or rethink the command so as not to use process substitution at all.

One option would be to create a temporary file and use that in the command:

```
set tmpfile `mktemp`
cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf > $tmpfile
printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:Some DNS,Some IP\n" >> $tmpfile
/usr/bin/openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout "selfsigned.key" \
    -out "selfsigned.crt" -subj "/C=XX/ST=XX/L=XX/O=XX/OU=XX/CN=Some IP" -extensions SAN \
    -config $tmpfile
rm -f $tmpfile
```

The fact that this might leave the temporary file lying around if interrupted is one of the reasons why the standard recommendation is not to write scripts in the C shell. (See [C Shell Programming Considered Harmful](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/csh) or [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt).)  With a POSIX shell, you can ensure that the temporary file is removed unless you brutally kill the script with `SIGKILL`.